# Run time casting in C, is it passable?

Tags: c, pointers, casting, switch-statement

let say I have a pointer to memory "pCurrentaddress", each access to the pointer have different type : uint8 , uint16, uint32 .

```
typedef unsigned char       uint8; 
typedef unsigned short int  uint16; 
typedef unsigned long  int  uint32;
```

I have a vTYPE var with value 8,16,32 and i want to do casting according to vTYPE, I don't want to use switch-case, since it will cost me in code size.

```
switch ( vTYPE )  
 { 
    case 32:            
    (*((uint32*)pCurrentaddress))++; 
    break; 
    case 16:             
    (*((uint16*)pCurrentaddress))++; 
    break; 
    case 8:             
    (*((uint8*)pCurrentaddress))++; 
    break; 
 }
```

any better solution ?
Tnx.

Comment: Have you actually *checked* how many bytes a `switch` like that will add to the generated code? I'll bet it's not many, which means it won't really matter unless you're coding for a minimal embedded platform, where ROM is counted in single-digit kilobytes.

Comment: I know you right, But I need to DO this switch-case for increasing in 1, decreasing in 1 setting value and so on... it is not optimized . best will be something like :
    (*((vTYPE*)pCurrentaddress))++;

Comment: OR even if I could just put this switch-case in a general function and use it each time. ?

Comment: Of *course* you can put the code in a function. And if you need to use it in multiple places you *should* place it in a function.And lastly, to answer your question, type-casting is a compile-time only thing, there's no way of doing anything similar run-time.

Comment: I tried making a function out of it, BUT it is impassable since functions are return by it predefined TYPE, If I am wrong Please correct me. I want to do it let say one function for increase and decrease in 1.

Comment: FUNCTION(pCurrentaddress)++;     style.

Comment: Can you please show us *what* `vTYPE` and `pCurrentAddress` are? I.e. their declarations. Also maybe tell us what the actual problem you try to solve is, what is your program trying to do?

Comment: The `switch`, even in an embedded system, will compile to a surprisingly small number of instructions.  On very small micros the compiler will optimise the code and may simply translate your `case`s as a jump table resulting in little more than a multiply and an add instruction, particularly if the `vType` values are contiguous.

Comment: vTYPE is uint8 with a value of 8,16 or 32 . pCurrentAddress is a *uint8 . nothing complicated. I want to use pCurrentAddress each time as a diffrent type according to vTYPE value. TNX

Comment: I'm not sure that can work but maybe you can try a solution with [union](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_unions.htm) ?

Comment: union is kind of what i do, Still need switch case.

Comment: By just doing this `(*((uint32*)pCurrentaddress))++; ` it work for me with `uint8` `uint16` and `uint32`

Comment: It will work , but wrong calculation can be made! wraparound issue.

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve? Incrementing LSB at a particular address only has implications when the value overflows for your particular value type. If you have control over your boundaries you could just do as @Missu notes in the comment.

Comment: If you really want to do this wrap your switch-case in a macro and perform the increment there, as you do in your own example. You should be golden.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand : "You should be golden" ?

Comment: @SionC Sorry about that. It means it should work.

Comment: @SionC Did you find a solution for this problem? If so, could you please create an answer and accept it.